# How reliable NTFS is for NAS/Backups

Tags: windows-7, backup, ntfs, nas

I'm currently building a Windows-based NAS (I have to use Windows due to the fact that there is no native client for Google Drive and Backblaze).  Is NTFS robust enough for such uses in terms of data integrity and resilience towards power failures?  I'll use a single 8TB drive for now (with plans to go up to 24TB) in the future.  Only one user will be needed (myself) and its purpose is to serve as a home backup/media streaming platform.

Also does this board contributes to any possible bottlenecks?
Board make and model - Intel DG41WV

Comment: It would depend on your use case and probably yes. Though using a single drive you might always encounter some form of silent data corruption.

Comment: of course MS knows that their filesystem can also be used on backup drives so they have to take care and test all the possible situations. If you need more reliability you have to use other ways like RAID, duplication or some checksum software solution